# scope when doing OO javascript callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, callback

Folks - I'm trying to learn how to write OO Javascript, I come from as3 OO background...
issue I'm having is with passing a class' method as a callback to another class...

in the example below, i create an instance of AppController class, and in it, i create an instance of ConnectionMonitor class. I pass one of AppController's methods to be called back by ConnectionMonitor. The calling back works fine, but seems that what's inside the callback function looses the scope of the class its in (AppController )...

any thoughts?

```
//in the HTML
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        new AppContoller().init();
    });
</script>


//in the js file

//AppController Class
var AppContoller = function(){
    this.body = $("body");

    this.init = function(){
        this.connection = new ConnectionMonitor();
        this.connection.detectInitialConnection( this.initialConnectionDetected );
    }

    //callback function I pass
    this.initialConnectionDetected = function(bool){
        if(bool){
            trace("app connected? "+bool); // logs - "app connected? true"
            this.showOnlineSwf();  //thows error - "Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'showOnline' "
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    this.showOnlineSwf = function(){
        trace("i'm online");

    }

}

//ConnectionMonitor Class
var ConnectionMonitor = function()
{   
    this.detectInitialConnection = function(callbackFunction){
        setTimeout(callbackFunction, 1000, [true]);
    }
}




function trace(arg){
    console.log(arg.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setTimeout will run the passed function bound to `window`.  You can override this with ES5's [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
this.connection.detectInitialConnection( this.initialConnectionDetected.bind(this) );
```

This doesn't work in older browsers, but the provided MDN link has a workaround.

Comment: thanks, that works in chrome but not in FF 3.6 ?? FF says "his.initialConnectionDetected.bind is not a function
[Break On This Error] this.connection.detectInitialConnect...tialConnectionDetected.bind(this) ); "

Comment: It's available starting in FF4, there is a compatability table in the article.  You can include the code clip MDN provides or google for "ES5 shim".

Answer (score 4):

Modify `init` to bind the callback to the original context:

```
this.init = function() {
    this.connection.detectInitialConnection(
        this.initialConnectionDetected.bind(this));
}
```

Unfortunately, [`bind` is not supported in all browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/), but you can capture the current value of `this` in a closure to achieve a similar effect:

```
this.init = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.connection.detectInitialConnection(function(detected) {
        that.initialConnectionDetected(detected);
    });
}
```

Yet another approach is to make `detectInitialConnection` capable of handling an optional context parameter:

```
this.detectInitialConnection = function(callbackFunction, _this){
    setTimeout(function() {
        callbackFunction.apply(_this || this, arguments);
    }, 1000, [true]);
}
```

You'd then call it like this:

```
this.init = function() {
    this.connection.detectInitialConnection(
        this.initialConnectionDetected, this);
}
```

The point in each of these examples is to retain a reference to the value of `this` from the context in which `detectInitialConnection` was called.

Answer (score 2):

this is tricky in javascript especially as it relates to constructors and passing functions around. If you do this it will work:

```
//AppController Class
var AppContoller = function(){
this.body = $("body");
var self = this;
this.init = function(){
    this.connection = new ConnectionMonitor();
    this.connection.detectInitialConnection( this.initialConnectionDetected );
}

//callback function I pass
this.initialConnectionDetected = function(bool){
    if(bool){
        trace("app connected? "+bool); // logs - "app connected? true"
        self.showOnlineSwf();
    }
    else{

    }
}

this.showOnlineSwf = function(){
    trace("i'm online");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.initialConnectionDetected` will pass the function, but without the information that it should be executed on the instance.

Calling `this.foo()` will pass this information, but only when called directly, not when passed around and called later (which is what you're doing).

You have to bind this information (i.e. the `this` value, which is the instance) using e.g. `.bind`:

```
this.connection.detectInitialConnection(this.initialConnectionDetected.bind(this));
```

Note that `.bind` is not available in older browsers, but there are shims available which mimic the behaviour of it.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but nobody seems to mention that `Function.prototype.bind` is [not supported in all browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). To make it work, you'll want to include [Kris Kowal's es5-shim library](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).