# Run callback function in originating scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I like to keep my javascript separated out into class files.  I've recently come across a need to be able to provide a callback function to a function in another javascript file access via dot notation as the function is part of an object.

So for instance if I have an object called MyObject, and it has a function called doSomething, and I wanted to have a callback for the doSomething function, but I am creating my instance of the object in another class file, and I pass my callback to the class file, it is run in that scope and not in the scope of the originating file.

```
FirstObject = function(options){

    var FirstObject = this;
    FirstObject.something = "somevalue";

    FirstObject.MyObject = new MyObject();
    FirstObject.MyObject.doSomething(param1, function(){//I need to be able to reference FirstObject.something here});
}
```

I know I can do this by firing an event in the second one, like: `$(document).trigger("doSomething-Finished")` and listen for this in the originating document, but I'd like to have more direct access.  I feel like it must be possible since this works with jQuery callbacks.

I've seen the answer on this question: [scope when doing OO javascript callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856967/scope-when-doing-oo-javascript-callbacks)

but I don't really understand what exactly he is doing in the solution and how to implement it for my specific situation.

Comment: I don't understand. You simply *can* reference `FirstObject.something` from that function? You just can't use `this`.

Comment: Please don't confuse (variable) *scope* with the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) *context*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES5 "bind" method on the callback function to ensure the desired scope is properly set, see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```js
FirstObject = function(options){

    var FirstObject = this;
    FirstObject.something = "somevalue";

    FirstObject.MyObject = new MyObject();

    var callback = function (){
        // "this" will be a reference to FirstObject, thanks to "bind" call below
    };

    FirstObject.MyObject.doSomething(param1, callback.bind(FirstObject));
}
```

Another way to keep a reference to FirstObject is by simply use dependency injection.
Here is an example using constructor injection but you also can use a setter function:

```js
FirstObject = function(options){

    var FirstObject = this;
    FirstObject.something = "somevalue";

    // pass FirstObject to sub object constructor
    // note that MyObject needs to store the reference for later use
    FirstObject.MyObject = new MyObject(FirstObject);


    FirstObject.MyObject.doSomething(param1, function(){//I need to be able to reference FirstObject.something here});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the function to your object:

```
FirstObject = function(options){

    var FirstObject = this;
    FirstObject.something = "somevalue";

    FirstObject.MyObject = new MyObject();
    FirstObject.MyObject.doSomething(param1, callback_function.bind(FirstObject.something));

    function callback_function(){
      // this will be FirstObject.something here
    }
}
```